# Set the original position of item in filtered ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I want get the original position when I select item in filtered `ListView`. 
This is my simple code.

My problem is to set the old position not the new one in filtered list view:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText sr;
  ListView lv_sr;
  String[] titre;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sr);
    lv_sr = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_sr);
    titre = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titre);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_itme, R.id.row_text, titre);

    lv_sr.setAdapter(adapter);
    initEvent();
}

private void initEvent() {

    sr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


    lv_sr.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent km = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Webhtml.class);

            km.putExtra("page",position); -------- this is my problem
            startActivity(km);

        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your Adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filter your ListView then every filtered View position has been also change according to the  amount of filtered views. So if you want to get the original position (Previous position or position before filtering) form OnItemClickListener on adapter. You can't get that any more.

You can create a hidden field for holing the original position.

```
String itemName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
int position_fo_item = Arrays.asList(titre).indexOf(itemName);

Intent km = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Webhtml.class);
km.putExtra("page",position_fo_item);
startActivity(km);
```

If it not work then create another array as 'titre_original' and assign it like 'titre' as well. then use it to get position like

```
String[] titre_original;
titre_original = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titre);    
int position_fo_item = Arrays.asList(titre_original).indexOf(itemName);
```

It will definitely work ...

Comment: Thank you for that answer : / but how i can create that ! if you have some time

Comment: can you share your Adapter?

Comment: What kind of problem you face? Is it show any err? or work fine but give wring position?

Comment: no i am gathering codes and i am trying to build this proj what u mean adapter? i thing i am using a string array adapter from android_asset

Comment: You can do one thing get position form your Array.

Comment: 10/10 captain working thank u for helping and thank u again for ur time can i have another qust?

Comment: the problem is solved but i have another question ?  what if i use input streamer to read a text file from asset to put strings in an array it will work ? did arrays.aslist will work ?